# Convert Array to string in Java/Groovy

Tags: arrays, string, groovy

I have a list like this:

```
List tripIds = new ArrayList()

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/steer", "root", "", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
        
sql.eachRow("SELECT trip.id from trip JOIN department WHERE organization_id = trip.client_id AND department.id = 1") {
  println "Gromit likes ${it.id}"
  tripIds << it.id
}
```

On printing tripids gives me value:

```
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,]
```

I want to convert this list to simple string like:

```
 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use `join`, e.g.,

```
tripIds.join(", ")
```

---

*Tangential*

If you want to create a list from another list you generally want something like `map` or `collect` as opposed to manually creating a list and appending to it, e.g. (untested):

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/steer", "root", "", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
def tripIds = sql.map { it.id }
```

Or if you **only** care about the resulting string:

```
def tripIds = sql.map { it.id }.join(", ")
```

Answer (score 17):

In groovy:

```
def myList = [1,2,3,4,5]
def asString = myList.join(", ")
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the [join method](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#join%28java.lang.String%29) that Groovy addes to Collection

```
List l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
assert l.join(',') == "1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = tripIds.toString();
str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try the following approach to convert list into String

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0; i<tripIds.size(); i++)
    {
        if(i!=0){
        sb.append(",").append(tripIds.get(i));
        }else{
            sb.append(tripIds.get(i));
        }
    }
    String listInString = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(listInString);
```

**Example**

```
ArrayList<String> tripIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        tripIds.add("a");
        tripIds.add("b");
        tripIds.add("c");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<tripIds.size(); i++)
        {
            if(i!=0){
            sb.append(",").append(tripIds.get(i));
            }else{
                sb.append(tripIds.get(i));
            }
        }
        String listInString = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(listInString);
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of work. Why repeat the code for appending `tripIds.get(i)` in both conditions? For that matter, why show the code for doing the creation twice; wouldn't it be more vertical-space-friendly to put it in a method and just call it from the example?

Comment: I assume you get paid by the line?